# Update list of items in a table from web service every X seconds

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a simple component that retrieves a list of items from a web service.

```
export class EventsList implements OnInit {
    events: Observable<Event[]>;

    constructor(public eventsService: EventsService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.eventsService.update();
        this.events = this.eventsService.events;
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class EventsService {
    events: Observable<Event[]>;

    update(): void {
        let url = 'event/view';
        let res = this.http.get(url);
        this.events = res
            .map((response: Response) => {
                return (<any>response.json()).map(item => {
                    return item;
                });
            });
    }
}
```

I want to keep this updated by polling the web service every X seconds. How should I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Observable.interval` and the `flatMap` operator as described below:

```
update(): void {
    let url = 'event/view';
    let res = Obsersable.interval(2000).flatMap(() => {
      return this.http.get(url);
    });
    this.events = res
      .map((response: Response) => {
        return (<any>response.json()).map(item => {
          return item;
        });
      });
}
```